# Manhwa comic where the protagonist was a fierce blonde princess who carries a sword and a shield with a slave boy whose powers are chains

Tags: story-identification, manga

It was about 2017 or 2018 when I first discovered it.

It was about a royal family and the princess was the heir to the queen. She was travelling to find a relic or a sword (I can't remember now) and she was also accompanied by one of the royal slaves. The slave was a boy, about the same as the age of the princess and his powers were chains. He was a champion from the survival arena being held in the kingdom, to fight for their lives. He could also transform into wolf form but last time I remember, he still couldn't control his powers that much so he died and resurrected. The two travelled and they encountered a master whom will train them.

Comment: "his powers were chains". Can you be a bit more specific about how that worked?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

As per [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/s7vt87/name_of_the_manga_mc_is_slave_gladiator_who/), this is likely *[Aire](https://myanimelist.net/manga/151006/Aire)*.

[image: Cover imag eof Aire]

> A journey to find the power of the lost Queen. Their great adventure begins.

Quoting the description from the post:

> I read long back a manhwa or manga I don't recall. The hero is a gladiator slave who uses chains to fight. There is blonde tsundere princess. Intially there is fight between fire wizard and mc. U actually think fire wizard is mc but nope he dies. Mc and princess go on some journey. Mc life is bound to princess through some spell.

### The Slave, Vera, with chains

[image: Vera, wielding this chains, in the gladiator pit]

It's not difficult to find it posted online but I'm uncertain of who is licensed to distribute it.

Search terms of `manhwa princess slave boy chains`

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is not licensed in English at all.